# How to multiprocess correctly? Invalid URL 'h': No schema supplied

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to scrape information from a fair amount to links, first I get the teamlinks (20) and then the playerlinks (550). I'm trying to speed up the process by using multiprocessing. But I have no experience using it and get below error when trying to run my code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "scrape.py", line 50, in playerlinks
    squadPage = requests.get(teamLinks[i])
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 519, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 462, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 313, in prepare
    self.prepare_url(url, params)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 387, in prepare_url
    raise MissingSchema(error)
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'h': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://h?
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "scrape.py", line 94, in <module>
        records = p.map(playerlinks, team)
      File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 266, in map
        return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
      File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 644, in get
        raise self._value
    requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'h': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://h?
```

I don't understand why since all the links start with http://.
Why isn't the multiprocess executing properly? Below is full code.

```
from lxml import html
import requests
import pandas as pandas
import numpy as numpy
import re
from multiprocessing import Pool

#Take site and structure html
page = requests.get('https://www.premierleague.com/clubs')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

def teamlinks():

    #Using the page's CSS classes, extract all links pointing to a team
    linkLocation = tree.cssselect('.indexItem')

    #Create an empty list for us to send each team's link to
    teamLinks = []

    #For each link...
    for i in range(0,20):

        #...Find the page the link is going to...
        temp = linkLocation[i].attrib['href']

        #...Add the link to the website domain...
        temp = "http://www.premierleague.com/" + temp

        #...Change the link text so that it points to the squad list, not the page overview...
        temp = temp.replace("overview", "squad")

        #...Add the finished link to our teamLinks list...
        teamLinks.append(temp)

    return teamLinks

#Create empty lists for player links
playerLink1 = []
playerLink2 = []

def playerlinks(teamLinks):



    #For each team link page...
    for i in range(len(teamLinks)):

        #...Download the team page and process the html code...
        squadPage = requests.get(teamLinks[i])
        squadTree = html.fromstring(squadPage.content)

        #...Extract the player links...
        playerLocation = squadTree.cssselect('.playerOverviewCard')

        #...For each player link within the team page...
        for i in range(len(playerLocation)):

            #...Save the link, complete with domain...
            playerLink1.append("http://www.premierleague.com/" + playerLocation[i].attrib['href'])

            #...For the second link, change the page from player overview to stats
            playerLink2.append(playerLink1[i].replace("overview", "stats"))

    return playerLink1, playerLink2

def position():
    #Create lists for position
    Position = []

    #Populate list with each position

    #For each player...
    for i in range(len(playerLink1)):

        #...download and process the one page collected earlier...
        playerPage1 = requests.get(playerLink1[i])
        playerTree1 = html.fromstring(playerPage1.content)

        #...find the relevant datapoint for position...
        try:
            tempName = str(playerTree1.cssselect('div.info')[7].text_content())
        except IndexError:
            tempTeam = str("NaN") 

        Position.append(tempName)
    return Position



if __name__ == '__main__':
    team = teamlinks()
    p = Pool()  # Pool tells how many at a time
    records = p.map(playerlinks, team)
    p.terminate()
    p.join()
```

Comment: What would an example of a `href` attribute look like?

Comment: <a href="/clubs/131/Brighton-and-Hove-Albion/overview" class="indexItem t36">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by using `p.map(playerlinks, team)` what python tries to do is to apply the function `playerlinks` on each element of `team`.

However as per your function definition the function `playerlinks` is designed to operate on the entire list at once. Do you see the issue?

This is what your `team` variable holds -

```
['http://www.premierleague.com//clubs/1/Arsenal/squad',
 'http://www.premierleague.com//clubs/2/Aston-Villa/squad',
 'http://www.premierleague.com//clubs/127/Bournemouth/squad',
 'http://www.premierleague.com//clubs/131/Brighton-and-Hove-Albion/squad',
 'http://www.premierleague.com//clubs/43/Burnley/squad',
 'http://www.premierleague.com//clubs/4/Chelsea/squad',
 'http://www.premierleague.com//clubs/6/Crystal-Palace/squad',
 'http://www.premierleague.com//clubs/7/Everton/squad',
 'http://www.premierleague.com//clubs/26/Leicester-City/squad',
 'http://www.premierleague.com//clubs/10/Liverpool/squad',
 'http://www.premierleague.com//clubs/11/Manchester-City/squad',
 'http://www.premierleague.com//clubs/12/Manchester-United/squad',
 'http://www.premierleague.com//clubs/23/Newcastle-United/squad',
 'http://www.premierleague.com//clubs/14/Norwich-City/squad',
 'http://www.premierleague.com//clubs/18/Sheffield-United/squad',
 'http://www.premierleague.com//clubs/20/Southampton/squad',
 'http://www.premierleague.com//clubs/21/Tottenham-Hotspur/squad',
 'http://www.premierleague.com//clubs/33/Watford/squad',
 'http://www.premierleague.com//clubs/25/West-Ham-United/squad',
 'http://www.premierleague.com//clubs/38/Wolverhampton-Wanderers/squad']
```

The multiprocessing library will try to schedule

```
playerlinks(['http://www.premierleague.com//clubs/1/Arsenal/squad'])
playerlinks(['http://www.premierleague.com//clubs/2/Aston-Villa/squad'])....
```

on `n` number of cores.

`playerlinks(['http://www.premierleague.com//clubs/1/Arsenal/squad'])` is what is throwing the error.

Modify your `playerlinks` function to operate on a single element from the `team` variable and then you'll see this issue going away.

Try something like this -

```
def playerlinks_atomic(teamLinks):
    squadPage = requests.get(teamLinks)
    squadTree = html.fromstring(squadPage.content)

    #...Extract the player links...
    playerLocation = squadTree.cssselect('.playerOverviewCard')

    #...For each player link within the team page...
    for i in range(len(playerLocation)):

        #...Save the link, complete with domain...
        playerLink1.append("http://www.premierleague.com/" + playerLocation[i].attrib['href'])

        #...For the second link, change the page from player overview to stats
        playerLink2.append(playerLink1[i].replace("overview", "stats"))
    return playerLink1, playerLink2
```

Comment: I kinda understand what you are saying, does that mean I have to rewrite the function so that it only processes one url to be able to multiprocess the function? Meaning no for loop.

Comment: you may also need to return the teamlinks parameter , because in your return data structure you have no way of knowing which input parameter gave which playerlinks.

Comment: @MisterButter - you are also much better off using multithreading for network bound operations such as the one you posted. Also please explicit set the number of cores/threads you want to use in ```p = Pool(#number of cores/threads)```

Comment: By default, a `Pool` will use the same number of processes as your CPU has cores. *This is a sensible default* for the kinds of things `Pool` is used for. Having more processes in the pool leads to the pool workers fighting over CPU resources. Using less processes means you're not using all available CPU resources.

Comment: @RolandSmith - For I/O-bound and Network bound tasks, it *may* make sense to create a quite a few more Pool processes than cores, since the processes will probably spend most their time blocked. Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: @ThalishSajeed It depends on the constraints of your setup. If you're using a 32-core AMD Threadripper in combination with a bad wifi connection the answer is most probably *no*. :-) If you' re using a raspberry pi with a gigabit wired connection then maybe *yes*. It also depends on the remote server, of course. That could very well be rate-limited to prevent bots like this from overloading it.